# What is the difference between the levels of Healing spells?

Tags: shadowrun-returns, shadowrun-dragonfall

In Dragonfall, there are multiple levels of healing spells available for purchase. Considering that the heal spell heals only one wound (the last damage your character took), what is the difference between each level of Heal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With each increased level of the Heal spell, the cooldown is reduced by 1 round.